# How to use \ as a separator

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to separate a string using '\' in javascript. It automatically converts into a escape sequence. Any help please.

Javascript

```
var str="file_path1\file_path2\file";
var rev=str.split("\");
```

This doesn't work.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ucw28/

ADDITIONAL DETAILS:

I'm uploading a file using input type= file.
I want to obtain the file name without using php.
And this problem occurred so I cannot escape the slash in the string itself.

Comment: You've to double the backslash, also in `str`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping backslash in string - javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618374/escaping-backslash-in-string-javascript)

Comment: I know that works but as you know I can't alter the string.
Anyways thank you.

Comment: I found this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-a-full-path-using-javascript). Can someone explain me the top answer in this. Please.

Comment: The regexp in that answer replaces backslashes and slashes with an empty string, not your solution. Which browser actually gives you the full path from file input and how? It supposed to be a fake path anyway... In IE you might get it when running a page locally, but it won't work on [a page loaded from a server](http://jsfiddle.net/URS4e/1/).

Comment: Thank you @Teemu.. yes it returns fake path but still the replace code in that answer worked for me. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslashes:

```
var str="file_path1\\file_path2\\file";
var rev=str.split("\\");
```

Comment: Actually the file path is an output of a default function in my program... so not in my hand.

Comment: Then just escape the slash when you use the `split` function: `str.split("\\");`

Comment: It returns 'file_path1ile_path2ile'. Don't know why, just it does.

Comment: @Rishi console.log() or alert() `str` before splitting, what you see?

Comment: Woah! It returns 'file_path1ile_path2ile'

Comment: I think it's because \f is formfeed.

Comment: Can you show the real piece of code you use in your page?