# How to escape backslash in java-script

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

```
var name= '<bean:write name="frmUser" property="name" filter="true" />';
```

When jsp render code then it appears like this

```
var name = 'Ishwar Lal \';
```

JavaScript shows error on it.

"Ishwar Lal \" is the sample value. I don't know what value will come. But issue appears when back slash come in javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping backslash in string - javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618374/escaping-backslash-in-string-javascript)

Comment: "Ishwar Lal \". Is the sample value. I don't know what value will come

Comment: Please, 
**1.** Say what you want to do exactly.
**2.** Say what the problem is.
**3.** Say what error appears.
**4.** Say where the error appears.
We cant do anyting, when you dont describe your problem!

Comment: Do you want the backslash to be included when you save it?

Comment: @Dyrandz Yes. Because it is business flow. But it is not necessary that backslash will come with every name.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` is this the error that you get?

Answer (score 0):

in Javascript you escape character with a backslash as well.
When you want to write one in a string, use `var str = "Ishwar Lal \\"`

Comment: "Ishwar Lal \". Is the sample value. I don't know what value will come.

Comment: sorry, I dont understand what your problem is exactly, could you explain it a bit more detailed?

Comment: I have updated my question. Basically in my db there are number of names. Any name may contains "\". I can not hard code only for "Ishwar Lal \\" value.

Answer (score 0):

This `javascript` function will escape all special characters..

```
function addslashes(str) {
      return (str + '')
        .replace(/[\\"']/g, '\\$&')
        .replace(/\u0000/g, '\\0');
    }
```

Credits: http://phpjs.org/functions/addslashes/

Comment: I have used your mentioned method but not resolved. This message is coming "Unterminated string Constant" in JS error. @Dyrandz