# Get Absolute path of the browsed file

Tags: file, coldfusion

I am using the following code to browse a file from my sytem :

```
<cfinput type="file" name="Document"  size="40" onChange="NAMESMALL.value = Document.value;" >
```

and following code to print the path of the file being browsed:

```
<cfoutput>#Document#</cfoutput>
```

I just want to get the absolute of the path being browsed. 
Because i have to use the path in an api and **not** perform any action on it lyk read,write upload etc.
Please suggest me some solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

This is not a coldfusion question, as when the page loads, what gets submitted is up to the browser.

this is then about how to get a form to submit a full path of an input[type=file]

which is answered here, basically cannot be done reliably:

[How to get the full path of the file from a file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176377/how-to-get-the-full-path-of-the-file-from-a-file-input)