# ASP.NET: Best way to grab a file path from a form thats residing in network share (UNC path)

Tags: javascript

In our intranet environment I am trying to have a way of (like file upload / telerik file explorer) selecting a file using a browser and then returning the path only. I need to save the path in database and users need to select the file from network shared drive.

For telerik explorer u need to implement custom provider to do that and I am unable to do it using file upload control.

Tips regarding a user friendly solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What about `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName()`?

Comment: But to do that i would require the full path first isn't it? From browser, file upload control is only returning the file name when I try getting the .value in Firefox/Chrome (required browsers), ANy ideas?

Comment: Oh, I got it now - so I changed the question tag since it's client-related rather than an ASP.NET-related issue. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can't be done because it would posses a security issue.

Please read these:

- http://forums.asp.net/t/1077850.aspx/1
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4176605/290343

Comment: sigh that was my only fear but well now it's verified. Thanks. Also thanks for editing the tag..you are right its client side stuff.