# Getting full path of the file selected via input file type

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, input-type-file, file-location

From my web page,i just want to browse a video file and then get its full path,so that i can use the path to stream the video file through VLC ,using the command line process.

For this purpose i dropped a file type control into my web page.

After selecting a file,when i check the value of the input field.Then i am only getting the name of the File

i.e If i select a file from my desktop named 1.mov,
then the location showed in the default text box with the input file type is `C:\Users\xx\Desktop\1.mov`

But when i check the value of the input field then it only gives the name of the video file i.e `1.mov`

Can anyone give me a suitable work around for this or may be some other way to get the full path of the selected file.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176377/how-to-get-the-full-path-of-the-file-from-a-file-input

Comment: But thats stating that there is no way of getting the full path.Is there any other work around?

Comment: You may need this file upload at your end and then you can stream this video form your file location.

Comment: But can i upload a file of say 2 gb using the file upload control.I know its possible by changing some lines in config file,but being a newbie in this i dnt know much abt it.Can u help me with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Must have to Upload file on server first,
then u can get root path using following method,

`Server.MapPath("~")`:It returns the physical path to the root of the application.

Comment: Is this the only way ? Or is there any other work around posible. Also i have the reuirements of streaming huge files say of 2 gb size.So uploading that big file to server,whether is permitted thru File upload control?

Comment: sorry but i never tried to upload huge files.and about path as per my knowledge u cant get the path of file before upload it .

Comment: Okay thanks gayathri  i will try it and update you.Thanks for the fast reply. :)

Comment: Do u know about registering a client side script in c#

Comment: Hi gayathri,thanks for the help ,i tried it the way you said and got it working,but need to find a way of uploading big video files using fileupload.