# How to use dynamically created image in another html file?

Tags: javascript, html, src

So I've tried unsuccessfully to copy the src of a dynamically created image through javascript in my index.html file, and I would like to create a new image in another html page where the src from the original is copied over and display that image. Any input or suggestions would be appreciated.
Relevant code below:

Full script on first page:

```
window.onload = function() {

var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');
var filecanvas = document.getElementById('check');
var context = filecanvas.getContext('2d');


fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var imageType = /image.*/;

    if (file.type.match(imageType)) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            fileDisplayArea.innerHTML = "";


            var img = new Image();
            img.src = reader.result;
            img.id = 'newimg';
            sessionStorage.setItem("CachedImage", img.src);



            fileDisplayArea.appendChild(img);


            var canvasimage = new Image();
            canvasimage.onload = function () {
            context.drawImage(canvasimage,100,200);
            };
            canvasimage.src = reader.result;
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        window.open('../markup/image.html');
    } else {
        fileDisplayArea.innerHTML = "File not supported!"
    }

});
```

}

Full script + html on second page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>

       window.onload = function() {
           var newimage = document.getElementById('ni');
           newimage.src = sessionStorage.getItem("CachedImage");
           newimage.alt = 'Cannot be displayed';
       };

</script>
<img id='ni' src="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Different pages do not share DOM! You need to somehow share the image src. Through LocalStorage/cookie/URL/database, etc.

Comment: document.getElementById('newimg'); will not return anything in the second page as your newimg is in the first page

Comment: you'll need to store the image (or it's source url) somewhere from the first page then retrieve it on the second page. You could use cookies or a database or something but you have to store it somewhere

Comment: save your image to local server then reference it via relative URL addressing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this on both Client side and server side. In client side you can use session storage or local storage option. If you want to retrieve data from server side then you need to create a function to return the value. Later you can access data from it.

Since you are passing only the path of a file, I would suggest you to use client side storage like sessions.

Source code : 
javascript code in first page:

```
var img = new Image(); 
img.src = reader.result;
img.id = 'newimg';
sessionStorage.setItem("CachedImage", img.src); // save image source into sessions
```

javascript code in second page:

```
 var newimage = new Image();
 newimage.id = 'ni';
 newimage.src = sessionStorage.getItem("CachedImage"); // retrieve image src from sessions
```

Comment: I've edited my post to show the script I'm using to get the user image.

Comment: I don't think  "reader.result" in page1 will return the correct path.you can add a alert to find the value. Eg: alert(reader.result);

Comment: you should also check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710302/html5-file-api-with-filename-path

Comment: After getting file path, Pls be mindful to escape  blackslash in them before you save them to sessions.Eg:  to save '\' in a string you need to enter '\\'

Comment: Thanks for the help/advice, I'll continue trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way send http headers with caching. But i wrote plugin of caching images in localStorage 2,2kb. [jQueryImageCaching](https://github.com/moledet/jQueryImageCaching)
Usage:

```
<img data-src="path/to/image">

<script>
    $('img').imageCaching();
</script>
```