# How fill TexBox by filepath from FileUpload control

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

Hello i got hidden FileUpload control, textBox where i wanna write url adrres or! filepath to some file, and button for call FileUpload. My problem is that i need instantly after user check in fileupload control some file and close popup window, fill TextBox with filepaths of that file.
I know how show filepath but i need do it automatically and that trap for me.
Here is what i got so far

```
<div class="ViewContent">
  <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" Width="317px" style="display: none"/>
  <input id="btnFileUpload" type="button" value="Add" runat="server" style="width: 70px" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="310px"/>
</div>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  btnFileUpload.Attributes.Add(
    "onclick",
    "document.getElementById('" + FileUpload2.ClientID + "').click();");  
}
```

So answer is simple: where should i put my check code for filling TextBox? something like this

```
if (FileUpload2.PostedFile != null)
{
  TextBox2.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will do the job:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(document).on('change', '#<%= FileUpload2.ClientID%>', function (e) {
            $('#<%= TextBox2.ClientID%>').val(e.target.files[0].name);
        });

            $('#<%=btnFileUpload.ClientID%>').click(function () {
                $('#<%= FileUpload2.ClientID%>').trigger('click');                
            });

    });
</script>
```

Add reference to jquery like below and remove the code form Page_Load().

```
<head runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
```

Or even:

```
<head runat="server">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And your Page_Load():

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //btnFileUpload.Attributes.Add(
    //"onclick",
    //"document.getElementById('" + FileUpload2.ClientID + "').click();");  
}
```

Comment: And this function is called automaticaly?Add reference is something like that in headcontent? <script src="C:\Users\Alexander\Documents\Isova\isova\isova\eSova\Scripts\jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
I tried it but nothing happens

Comment: Because probably jquery is not attached. I have update my answer to show how to attach it.

Comment: Thank you for patient. SO now its working /but i dont know how>D/ and one little problem that in TextBox i got onlz name of file. Can i somone get fullpath?

Comment: You may have code in codebehind to run the uploader- it's causing running it twice. Answer to your second question, you can't get full path from file upload. Some browser may support it. Please see this:[How to get the full path of the file from a file input](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4176377/690329)

Comment: OU thank zou so much man. I get it now. I spend my whole day to deal with this and i think that i get it. I have to learn Jquery in future realy nice feature:)

Comment: I am sure you will love jquery. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As you want to get filename instantly, you should use javascript something like this:

```
var fu1 = document.getElementById("FileUpload1");
alert("You selected " + fu1.value);
```

let me know if anything else.

Comment: and where I should call this function? When i need fill my TextBox instantly after user check file from FileUpload control. Because i can get filepath in pure csharp but i need it after FileUpload close popup window

Comment: For example I can call javascript which works fine like this onchange="alert('you selected the file: '+ this.value)" on FileUpload but i need this value save in code=behind. Do you know what should i do?

Comment: document.getElementById("txtBox1").value=fu1.value;

Comment: Ok that look nice but not working i got in FIlUpload onchange and this event call javascript function like this function Test()
        {
            var fu1 = document.getElementById('FileUpload2');
            document.getElementById('TextBox2').value = fu1.value;
        }
I not good in javascript can you help me? Is something wrong with this script? Because when i put alert('value of var: '+fu1.value) nothing show.