# Extremelly Quick Start in HTML

Tags: html

I want to make a HTML page with two components on it: Button and Edit. If I press on button then OpenDialogFile executes. After choosing a file, I want to see it's full path (f.e. "C:/temp_folder/superText.txt") inside my Edit.

```
<body>
<h1>FileCreator Page!</h1>

<form action="createCSV" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="fileName" value="D:/">
    <input type="file" value="Choose CSV" title="Choose"> <!-- title is not working-->
    <input type="submit" value="Load file into DB">
</form>
<body>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. SO is for help with problems, we won't do your work for you.

Comment: my value and title do not work

Comment: You cannot fetch the full path from a file input.

Comment: ok. So what is your proposal? Ho can I get my goal? I am java programmer, but know nothing about building GUI-interface using HTML = (

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the full path of the file from a file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176377/how-to-get-the-full-path-of-the-file-from-a-file-input)

Comment: @nightin_gale — You cannot achieve your stated goal, but as I can't see an app that tells the user where they just picked a file from and being a very useful one, your stated goal probably isn't your real goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to security reasons you can not set a value for an input type file tag. 
Look at this thread for further information to this topic: [set value for input type file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Also there is no attribute called "title", the text shown on the button is predifined by the browser and can not be changed.

Comment: ok, thx! I didn't know HTML can't do it. I supposed you gave me another ways. Now I am reading about JSF. I jope it will be the solution of my trouble)