# How do I fetch the full filepath that is displayed in browse button

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Full path from file input using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489133/full-path-from-file-input-using-jquery)
>   [how to resolve the C:\fakepath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)

I am using multiple file upload in my application and I want to fetch the full file path that is displayed in the browse widget.

For example, say the file path is "home/administrator/Pictures/bird.jpeg". I am able to fetch only the file name (bird.jpeg). Using PHP and Firefox as my browser, is there any alternative to obtaining the full file path?

Answer (score 0):

You can not get it because of browser security settings.