# used <input type=file> to browse & choose image in HTML.But it selects only image.But I want to select with its full path location in HTML

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the full path of the file from a file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176377/how-to-get-the-full-path-of-the-file-from-a-file-input)

I have used  to browse and choose an image file in HTML. But it selects only the image. But I want to select with its full path location in HTML. How to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The full file path isn't exposed to you for security reasons. Why do you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from serve-let can try like this

```
<form action="upload-script-url" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and from httpRequest you can get the file in that form.
PS:
When a file is selected by using the input type=file object, the value of the value property depends on the value of the "Include local directory path when uploading files to a server" security setting for the security zone used to display the Web page containing the input object.

The fully qualified filename of the selected file is returned only when this setting is enabled. When the setting is disabled, Internet Explorer 8 replaces the local drive and directory path with the string C:\fakepath\ in order to prevent inappropriate information disclosure.

check this questioin [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489133/full-path-from-file-input-using-jquery)