# Classic ASP with VBScript

Tags: asp-classic

I have created an upload file functionality using `<input type="file" name="attachment"/>`. I need to know the absolute path of the file attached, for e.g if I browse file from the location *D:/MyFolder/Test.text*

How can I get this location using VBScript?

Comment: You can't. Modern browsers hide the full path for security reasons. See [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3489133/447356) as well.

Comment: you could get it with clientside vbscript (works only in IE) and changing some security settings in IE. is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

> According to the specifications of HTML5, a file upload control should
>   not reveal the real local path to the file you have selected, if you
>   manipulate its value string with JavaScript. Instead, the string that
>   is returned by the script, which handles the file information is
>   C:\fakepath.
>
> This requirement is already implemented in Internet Explorer 8 – the
>   real path to the file will be shown only if the page that contains the
>   control is added to the trusted sites collection of the browser. That
>   made sense; essentially the browser is feeding that lame C:\fakepath\
>   text in.

[Reference](https://davidwalsh.name/fakepath)

You can Just get the name of selected file using this:

```
var fileName = fileInput.value.replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "");
```