# How To Get Real Path Of A File Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, file-upload

how to get a real path of a file using input type="file" i.e :

HTML Code:

```
<input type="file" id="fileData"/>
```

when user click on brows button, he will select a file, so i wanted a path from where he selected. Through Jquery (or any possible way ) if i get a value of 'filedata' i.e:

Jquery :

```
 var filename = $('#fileData').val();
```

it gives like this `C:\fakepath\SO_Status.xlsx`

but what i realy wanted is path of a file and not data inside a file / no need to upload a file `C:\filesFolder\SO_Status.xlsx` (assuming 'SO_Status.xlsx' file present in fakepath)

Comment: Most modern browsers will not let you have this information, as it can give away the file structure of the client machine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489133/full-path-from-file-input-using-jquery

Comment: Use $('#fileData')[0].files[0].path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do is not possible due to security reasons.

Also, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15201258/706273

Comment: i gone through it, but it is not what i relay wanted

Comment: @RajeshHatwar That's what I'm saying - due to security reasons it is not possible to do it.

Comment: Also, why would you like to know the full path? There might be a workaround for your particular needs.

Comment: yes i have, I am working on a Library Software. some times users will keep E-books on some location and while entering a Non-Book details they save soft copy path of it

Comment: In this case the `<input>` element will not be sufficient. You will have to write your own local-filepath selector using the underlaying technology (PHP, or any other). Check this question: http://bit.ly/1pdMzZn

Comment: @RajeshHatwar Use $('#fileData')[0].files[0].path