# Show full path input file html clients side

Tags: angularjs, node.js, html, client, emscripten

I have a html page run on client side and 1 input file. How to input file show full path when user select file. (Internet Explorer is ok. But i want on chrome, Firefox). Node js or angular can do? Thank you!

Comment: node.js can't do anything on the client side...

Comment: Uhm, so what about AngularJS?

Comment: Depends on the browser settings of the client: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489133/full-path-from-file-input-using-jquery#answer-3489167

Answer (score 0):

You can using jQuery

`location.href` will get the full URL,include the file name and the urk query

```
$fullpath = location.href;
$('.myInput').val();
```