# can not get file path from image browse in javascript onclick button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-uploading

i have a simple browse which accepts only images. But after onclick button i can not get the full path in javascript so that i can send them to server by jquery post. i am only getting the filename.

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function post_ad() {

        var img = document.getElementById('img1'),
        tempimg= img.value;

        alert(tempimg);

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'process.php',
            data: {
                tempimg: tempimg
             },
             success: function (html) {

             }
         });
    }

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="img1" name="img1" accept="image/*" type='file'>

<input type="button" onclick="post_ad()" value="click">
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the Javascript part completely?

Comment: i dont understand, which javascript part ?

Comment: I mean, if you remove the `onclick="post_ad()"`

Comment: You cannot get full path according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489133/full-path-from-file-input-using-jquery

Comment: You can not get full path but getting name you can generate it accordingly at server side as you know in which folder that image remains

Comment: You can not get a real path from file input. And even if it was possible you would post the path, not the file, so it wouldn't make sense. If you want to post the image using ajax, then it's been answered before, f.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447435/ajax-upload-image

Comment: thank You. i will hardcode the full path on server side.

Comment: Your example should give you the URL .. it would say for example `C:/fakepath/filename.png` ? This is a **browser security implementation**. Browser won't allow access to your system disk structure.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons its forbidden. Here its a more complete answer:
[How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)