# Blazor Input File Component (physical path)

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I want to get the physical file path.
I tried a few options. `<input type="file">`
I need to get the physical path to pass it to another API in windows service on the same machine.
is it possible or not?

Comment: show us what you have tried and your errors.

Comment: When that _physical file path_ is on an Apple Mac or an Android phone, what would your windows service do with that?

Comment: @henk-holterman   i want to implement one of them . and always was run on windows

Comment: No, Blazor always runs in a Browser so, because _it could_ run on Android you only get APIs that run everywhere.

Comment: I need to upload file to 3rdParty with file name !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

It is not allowed because of security concerns. All modern web browsers have restricted this. Please see some of the many StackOverflow answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4176605/1158845
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3489167/1158845