# Using input type="file" to obtain full filepath

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, google-chrome

On our ASP MVC view, we have a section where the user can select an attachment using the `file` input type and the file path of that file is saved in a field in our SQL database. This works perfectly in IE and, up until recently, I could have sworn worked in Chrome, however I now notice that when you navigate to the file only the file NAME gets saved, not the full path. Has anyone had any similar issues with Chrome and/or know of a work-around?

FYI - This is a small intranet app used by *maybe* a handfull of employees so security beyond anything basic we already have set up isn't a huge concern.

```
                <div class="M-editor-label" >
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Attachment, new { type = "file" })
                </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the full path (server-side) of a file uploaded using Firefox, IE, Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/269015/209259)

Comment: Look at the post provided by Erik, it contains a solution.  Use JavaScript to push the path in a hidden when posting the form.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see anything in that post about a solution could you be more specific?